# nth-child odd / even wordpress loop

Tags: css-float, wordpress, css-selectors

I've got a standard Wordpress loop where I want the images to float to the right and left on odd and even row numbers respectively.

The problem I have is that the .featured:nth-child(odd) is getting applied to all the featured images floating all images to the left.

Is it an issue with the loop? Do I need to use a foreach loop instead?
Any help much appreciated. Thanks

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

   <figure class="featured">
    <img src="#" width="230" height="230">
   </figure>

   <div class="content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
   </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>


CSS:
.featured {
margin: 0 0 0 20px;
width: 228px;
border: 1px solid #333; 
}
.featured:nth-child(odd){
float: left;

}

.featured:nth-child(even) {
float: right;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that figure.featured div.content are located on one level of structure. And all figures are recognizing like nth-child(odd). In this situation div.content is a "nth-child(even)"-elements.